# inner product space and linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
V
be a finite dimensional inner product space and
T
be a linear operator on 
V.
Then there exist a unique linear operator
S
such that
(Ta,b) =(a,Sb) 
a and b belongs to V.

I want to know how to define 
S
such that condition hold.

Comment: Is $(\cdot,\cdot)$ referring to the inner product on $V$? If so, then you are talking about the adjoint of a linear operator.

Comment: If we represent $T$ as a matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis, $S$ will be the transpose (or conjugate-transpose if $V$ is over $\Bbb C$) of $T$

Comment: how to prove this please explain a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Given $b$, define $L_b(a) = \langle Ta, b \rangle$.  Note that $L_b$ is linear.  Thus, by the (finite dimensional) Riesz representation theorem, there exists a vector $y$ such that $L_b(a) = \langle a, y \rangle$ for all $a$.  Now define $S$ to be the function that maps $b$ to this vector $y$.

By construction, we have that 
\begin{equation}
\langle Ta,b \rangle = L_b(a) = \langle a, Sb \rangle
\end{equation} 
for all $a,b$.  You can easily check that $S$ is linear.